# Float conversion in a Service developed in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a Service developed in Delphi with DataSnap and Tethering that sends me information to connected clients. Now, some of the fields are float, when you convert them to string with the function "FormatFloat ('$, 0. ###', field)" it gives me another format, ie it does not send me in the format I have configured In Windows, "." For thousands separator and "," for decimals, but on the contrary. I want 15674.45 to be $ 15.647,45 and not $ 15,647.45. But I do not want to force the format.

```
procedure TServerContainerSGV40.tapServicioResourceReceived(const Sender: TObject; const AResource: TRemoteResource);
var
  identifier, hint, cadena: string;
  ID_PRODUCTO: Integer;
  codigo, descripcion: string;
  ppp, stock, precio_venta: Real;
begin
  if AResource.ResType = TRemoteResourceType.Data then
  begin
    identifier := Copy(AResource.Hint, 1, Pos('}', AResource.Hint));
    hint := AResource.Hint.Replace(identifier, '');
    cadena := AResource.Value.AsString;
    if cadena = 'Get IP' then EnviarCadena(AResource.Hint, 'Envío IP', GetLocalIP);
    if hint = 'Datos Producto' then
    begin
      if cadena.Length > 0 then
      begin
        with usGetDatosProducto do
        begin
          ParamByName('CODIGO').AsString := cadena;
          Execute;
          ID_PRODUCTO := ParamByName('ID_PRODUCTO').AsInteger;
          codigo := ParamByName('CODIGO').AsString;
          descripcion := ParamByName('DESCRIPCION').AsString;
          ppp := ParamByName('PPP').AsFloat;
          stock := ParamByName('STOCK').AsFloat;
          precio_venta := ParamByName('PRECIO_VENTA').AsFloat;
        end;
        if ID_PRODUCTO > 0 then
        begin
          cadena := Format('%s;%s;;PRECIO:'#9'%s;P.P.P.:'#9'%s;STOCK:'#9'%s', [
            codigo, descripcion, FormatFloat('$ ,0', precio_venta),
            FormatFloat('$ ,0.##', ppp), FormatFloat(',0.###', stock)
          ]);
          EnviarCadena(identifier, 'Envío Datos Producto', cadena);
        end
        else
          EnviarCadena(identifier, 'Mostrar Mensaje', 'Código de Producto No Existe');
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Please stop tag spamming. Your question has absolutely nothing to do with tethering, datasnap or a service; it's entirely about formatting a floating point number to a localized currency string. The fact you're doing so in a service does not make the question about service programming, and the fact you mentioned both tethering and DataSnap does not make the question about tethering or DataSnap programming. Tags have relevance and meaning here; apply only the ones that actually apply to your question. Thanks.

Comment: I want this format, but I don't want to force it. Er, what ? Do you want a specific format or not? Anyway, formatting currency is something to be done on display to the user. Not for behind the scenes data transfer. Don't format the currency when transferring the data. Format it only on display.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `FormatFloat()` uses the global `SysUtils.ThousandsSeparator` and `SysUtils.DecimalSeparator` variables, which *are* initialized from OS settings at program startup:

```
FormatFloat('$#,##0.00', field);
```

If you want to force a specific format regardless of OS settings, use the overloaded version of `FormatFloat()` that takes a `TFormatSettings` as input:

```
var
  fmt: TFormatSettings;

fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
fmt.ThousandsSeparator := '.';
fmt.DecimalSeparator := ',';
FormatFloat('$#,##0.00', field, fmt);
```

Comment: Isn't TFormatSettings a record type? Did that change in recent delphi versions or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnEasley: yes, it is a record, and always has been. But it also has a `Create` method (constructor) for initializing the record with default values from the OS.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi versions from D2009 (at least) you can [specify format settings](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FormatFloat@string@Extended.html) for given operation and initialize these settings either by Windows default settings or modify needed formatting fields.

```
function FormatFloat(const Format: string; Value: Extended): string; overload;
function FormatFloat(const Format: string; Value: Extended; 
                     const FormatSettings: TFormatSettings): string; overload;
```

And I wonder - is it impossible to form all string with only `Format` function?